# add to cart grouped product from shop page woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to wordpress, please let me know how the following can be done.

I am displaying woocommerce grouped product in a wordpress page via short code.
I have removed category title under product name via css

Is it possible to display the child products and add to cart button( instead of view products ) with the validation so that i don't have to go to product page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzqNs.png)

Thanks in advance